Minimal DFA for Counting Distinct Symbols Modulo 3
I am seeking a minimal Deterministic Finite Automaton (DFA) that determines the number of distinct symbols in a given word, modulo 3, over an alphabet of size N.
Specifically, the DFA should have the following properties:
Input: A word w over the alphabet of size N.
Output: The DFA should enter one of three final states: Q[0], Q[1], or Q[2].
Acceptance condition: The DFA enters state Q[k] if and only if the number of distinct symbols in w is congruent to k modulo 3.
My current approach involves constructing a DFA with 2^(3N) states, where each state represents a unique subset of distinct elements encountered. However, this solution is clearly far from optimal.
I would appreciate guidance on constructing a minimal DFA for this problem, or insights into more efficient approaches to reduce the state space.

I expect that the best you can do is an automaton that has close to $2^N$ states, one for each unique subset of elements that have been encountered so far.  (I'm not sure where your $2^{3N}$ came from, but $2^N$ is the correct number of such subsets.)  You can do slightly better for some $N$: if $N=3k+2$, then I expect $2^{N} - N$ states suffice, as all the states corresponding to a subset with $3k+1$ or $3k+2$ unique elements can be merged into a single state.  However I doubt you can do better than that.
I expect you can prove this using the Myhill-Nerode theorem that it's not possible to do significantly better.  In particular, I suggest you identify all of the equivalence classes; then the number of such classes is the size of the minimal DFA.

Thank you for your answer. I'm wondering about the necessity of having a state for each possible subset, given that we only need to output the set size modulo 3. Is there a possibility of achieving a sub-exponential state count while maintaining correctness? How can we be sure the current approach represents a lower bound for the number of states?

@AviTal, I think I've already answered all of those questions.  I suggest that you find the Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes, as suggested in the answer.  Then you'll be able to answer those questions.  You could start by calculating the equivalence classes for small values of $N$ ($N=1,2,3,4,5,...$) if you are having difficulty getting started.

A related language: Size comparison of NFA and minimal DFA. "Let $L_n$
be the language of all words over ${a_1,\dots,a_n}$
that don't contain all letters."
